# Input <select> selected is not working correctly in PHP by comparing 2 arrays

Tags: php

I have

```
3 <select></select>
```

with 8 options inside (Array_1 with 8 position). All options value are the same.

What i am trying to do is that I want to make the Value in Array_2 to be the Selected value.

However, looks like my loop is not working correctly.

```
    $array_1[]="value1";
    $array_1[]="value2";
    $array_1[]="value3";
    $array_1[]="value4";
    $array_1[]="value5";
    $array_1[]="value6";
    $array_1[]="value7";
    $array_1[]="value8";

    $array_2[]="value1";
    $array_2[]="value3";
    $array_2[]="value4";



for($i=0;$i<count($array_2);$i++){

    echo '<select name="product_header_image[]">';

    for($b=0;$b<count($array_1);$b++){
        if(in_array($array_2[$i],$array_1)){
            echo '<option selected VALUE="'.$array_1[$b].'" >'.$array_1[$b].'</option>';
        }else{
            echo '<option VALUE="'.$array_1[$b].'" >'.$array_1[$b].'</option>';
        }       
    }

    echo '</select>';
    echo '<br>';

}
```

[image]

Anyone know whats wrong with my coding? what I want to achieve is the right hand side of the screenshot.

Comment: remove the second for-loop, not the code inside it just the for command

Comment: nope, it's not working. I still need the 8 options in each Select on top of right side screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace this check:

```
if(in_array($array_2[$i], $array_1)) {
   ...
}
```

on this:

```
if($array_2[$i] == $array_1[$b]) {
   ...
}
```

[Demo here](http://phpio.net/s/iiy)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your scenario, but this might be what you are looking for. It generates a dropdown with all the elements from both arrays, and highlights the selected ones.

```
$array_1[]="value1";
$array_1[]="value2";
$array_1[]="value3";
$array_1[]="value4";
$array_1[]="value5";
$array_1[]="value6";
$array_1[]="value7";
$array_1[]="value8";

$array_2[]="value1";
$array_2[]="value3";
$array_2[]="value4";

echo '<select name="product_header_image[]" multiple>';

foreach ($array_1 as $elem1) {
    echo '<option VALUE="'. $elem1 .'" >' . $elem1 .'</option>';
}

foreach ($array_2 as $elem2) {
    $selected = '';
    if( in_array($elem2, $array_1) ) $selected = 'selected '; 
    echo '<option '. $selected . 'VALUE="' . $elem2 . '" >'.$elem2.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
echo '<br>';
```